# Recommended algorithms for word similarity

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, matching, similarity

I'm researching viable algorithms/solutions to implement and solve following problem: 
**match users based on their common interests**

Example:
U1: skiing, asian culture, meditation, java, crypto
U2: yoga, meditation, management, travel tips USA
U3: programming, travelling, oriental cuisine

I'm considering three dimensions based on word similarity:

- Dictionary synonyms

  - [wordnet](https://wordnet.princeton.edu/) synsets
- Close semantic similarity (programming > java, travelling > travel tips USA)

  - So far I have considered [Levenshtein_distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance)
- Loose semantic similarity (asian culture >> oriental cuisine, programming >> crypto, asian culture >> yoga, yoga >> meditation)

  - Not sure at all, played with [word2vec](https://code.google.com/archive/p/word2vec/)

Based on these approaches I would like to calculate a relevancy score and match users accordingly.

Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Levenshtein distance** was not very useful for capturing semantic similarity in my experiments.

**Wordnet** worked well but was slow for large set of words

**Word2Vec** is good approximation for wordnet but not as comprehensive in capturing all the related words

Also suggest you look at the **graph embedding algorithm** used in **Starspace from Facebook** and specially the use case around Facebook page likes and recommendations